# JSON patch rfc6902: Sequential operation and index

Tags: javascript, json, json-patch

In JSON patch, how should one use the index for subsequent operation on the same array. For example, consider

```
 var source = { colors: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'] };
 var target = { colors: [] };
```

patch doc (operations)

```
[{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/0"},
{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/1"},
{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/2"}]
```

If I consider the index of the source, the above indexes are correct. When I apply it sequentially though, the index are incorrect. That is if I remove, 0 th and 1st index, there is no element at index 2.

I could think of couple of ways to handle this. Either group all delete operation on an array, then keep a temporary structure to hold/manipulate change in index during deletion. Or, keep the index relative to a mutating value

```
[{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/0"},
{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/0"},
{"op":"remove","path":"/colors/0"}]
```

it makes sense if the operation is considered mutation of a resource in sequence.

Is there any standard on this. I cannot see anything about it in the spec. [A.4.  Removing an Array Element](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#page-13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any standard on this

The [section about the evaluation of the operations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-3) seems to be quite clear:

```
Evaluation of a JSON Patch document begins against a target JSON
document.  Operations are applied sequentially in the order they
appear in the array.  Each operation in the sequence is applied to
the target document; the resulting document becomes the target of the
next operation.
```